# How to calculate temperature rise of PCB polygon?

Tags: power, pcb-design, temperature, thermal, ground-plane

I'm designing a PCB where I have a polygon that carries current from one terminal to two pads, each pad should pull 33 Amperes, so a total of 66 Amperes running through that polygon.

How can I calculate the temperature rise of that polygon?
What software can be of help?

I have the currents and polygon shape, dimensions & copper weight.
It's on an FR4 PCB, it's an external layer, the ambient temperature should be 25C.

Comment: I bet that Autodesk Fusion 360 could do this. I haven't used it. Looks like there's a free trial: https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360

Comment: Knowing the electrical characteristics isn't enough. You also need to model the thermal characteristics of the board and its environment.

Comment: The maximum temp rise will be the smallest joint or pad and diffuse according to thermodynamics and convection cooling. A bus bar may be considered a better choice, yet many stovetops use solder fillets to thicken the grid cheaper.